# How can I print whole content of a directory including sub-directories, sub-sub-directories and files?

Tags: python

I have a certain directory but it is unknown to me how many sub directories or sub-sub directories it contains.
In short, I want to print all of the files in all of the directory, and sub directory, and sub sub directory etc.
I assume it has to be recursive? I do not know to any level the sub directories can go so I guess I'm trying to print whole directory try.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
```

It did not work.
I am trying to literally print anything that can be achieved from my path, all files

I'm expecting to print everyf ile that can somehow be achieved from my path

Comment: *it did not work* how? what did not work? what were you expecting? what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are not printing anything, you're only looping, here's how to print the filenames from your loop (and file paths):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        file_name = file
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        print(file_name)
        print(file_path)
```

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your comment. I understand but I think I did not explain myself good enough:
The directory contains subdirectories, os.walk won't go into the subdirectories

Comment: Won't this exclude empty dirs?

Comment: @wjandrea OP wants to print files, not directories, I assume, per the question.

Comment: @JohnnyS Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57694861/edit) to explain in more detail